# Python Why do my changed datatypes go back to their former dataype after I save them to a .csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, types, filesize

.info of Initial dataframe

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 2851191 entries, 0 to 3168737
Data columns (total 6 columns):
READ_TIME             object
SVC_PT_ID             float64
CUSTOMER_ID           object
SIGNAL_NAME           object
SIGNAL_DESCRIPTION    object
VALUE                 float64
dtypes: float64(2), object(4)
memory usage: 152.3+ MB
```

Then I change datatypes of "CUSTOMER_ID", "SIGNAL_NAME" and "SIGNAL_DESCRIPTION" to "category"

```
test = new_inkl_24.astype({"CUSTOMER_ID": "category", "SIGNAL_NAME":"category", "SIGNAL_DESCRIPTION":"category"})
```

I check if everything worked and the file size is reduced

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2851191 entries, 0 to 2851190
Data columns (total 7 columns):
Unnamed: 0            int64
READ_TIME             object
SVC_PT_ID             float64
CUSTOMER_ID           category
SIGNAL_NAME           category
SIGNAL_DESCRIPTION    category
VALUE                 float64
dtypes: category(3), float64(2), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 95.2+ MB
```

Everything worked perfectly. So now I save my dataframe to a .csv-fie

```
test.to_csv('test.csv')
```

And here´s the problem:
The file size is not reduced anymore. The csv is exactly as large as the initial one with the old datatypes for the columns. 
Also when I import the file into my Jupyter notebook again, the datatypes are switched back to the intial ones.

```
# Load data
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2851191 entries, 0 to 2851190
Data columns (total 8 columns):
Unnamed: 0            int64
Unnamed: 0.1          int64
READ_TIME             object
SVC_PT_ID             float64
CUSTOMER_ID           object
SIGNAL_NAME           object
SIGNAL_DESCRIPTION    object
VALUE                 float64
dtypes: float64(2), int64(2), object(4)
memory usage: 174.0+ MB
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

CSV is a text format that doesn't have data types; in effect, it's all strings, as you get from the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). Pandas does have a bunch of data types and will try to select appropriate ones per column when loading a CSV, but you can [specify data types](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#specifying-column-data-types) to guide it. You can also choose to save in a file format that supports types, such as [HDF](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#hdf5-pytables) or [Pickle](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#pickling) (which also means dataframes can be stored using [shelve](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html)).